# How do you Load an Image in Pygame Properly?

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I try to load an image of some fries (an enemy in the game), it loads the sprite. I think, the image is blank. How do I properly load the image to make it appear?

I've tried to change the method of loading the image, opting for loading the image from the outside of the class instead of the inside.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# how big the game window is
wind = pygame.display.set_mode((600,700))

pygame.display.set_caption("Heart Attack")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 0.8

fries = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = fries
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)

move = True
Enemy((100, 300))

while move:
    pygame.time.delay(1)
#kill switch
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            move = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
#moves character
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel
 # makes the character not clone itself
    wind.fill((0,0,0))      
 # draws and displays character with the color red
    pygame.draw.rect(wind, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I need the sprite to show up, but it shows up blank. I want it to spawn in the middle of the screen, hence the `center = pos`.

Answer (score 1):

The image is probably loaded just fine; but you never actually blit it to the screen surface.

You could change your code to this:

```
...
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Enemy((100, 300)))

move = True
while move:
...
    sprites.draw(wind)
    pygame.display.update()
```

using a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), which is pygame's default way of drawing sprites.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Sorry, I've been away for a bit. When I try your method, the sprite seems to flicker. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @RedTrio Hard to say without seeing the final code, but maybe you call `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` multiple times in the loop? Make sure you first clean the screen (with e.g. with `fill()`), then draw your sprites, then call `display.flip` or `display.update` once.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, when I do that, they still flicker, but just a bit less. I'm consulting with my instructor and he's suggested that I refresh each character separately. So I'm going to try that and hopefully it'll work. Thanks for the help!